Seaborn legend not matching with plot lines
I have the following code:
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

v_exponents = range(2, 9)
vs = [2 ** exponent - 1 for exponent in v_exponents]
df = pd.read_csv('data/out/erdos_renyi_graph/path_lengths_dfs/stats.csv')
for v in vs:
    df_filtered = df[df['V'] == v]
    print(df_filtered)
    sns.lineplot(data=df_filtered, x="E", y="fraction_connected")
plt.legend(title="V", labels=vs)
plt.savefig(f'src/main/python/erdos_renyi_graph/path_lengths_dfs/doc/img/ErdosRenyiGraph-PathLengthsDFS.png')

It gives this output:

Why is the legend screwed up?  There are alternating thin and thick lines, two of each color.  Moreover, it doesn't show all the colors, only blue through red.

Note that your question is a bad fit for StackOverflow, as you don't provide easy test data.

import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

v_exponents = range(2, 9)
vs = [2 ** exponent - 1 for exponent in v_exponents]
df = pd.read_csv('data/out/erdos_renyi_graph/path_lengths_dfs/stats.csv')
labels = []
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for v in vs:
    df_filtered = df[df['V'] == v]
    print(df_filtered)
    sns.lineplot(data=df_filtered, x="E", y="fraction_connected", label=v)
handles, labels = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()

# Create a single legend
ax.legend(handles, labels)

plt.savefig(f'src/main/python/erdos_renyi_graph/path_lengths_dfs/doc/img/ErdosRenyiGraph-PathLengthsDFS.png')


ax.get_legend_handles_labels() isn't needed here. You can just call ax.legend(). In general, Seaborn doesn't work well with matplotlib's legend function. That's because seaborn creates multiple matplotlib elements (e.g. an error band) for one "logical" element. Your idea to use sns.lineplot(..., label=v) works here, but it is not a general solution.

Seaborn's way to create your plot would be to work with hue and let Seaborn do the filtering (and automatically add a legend): sns.lineplot()data=df, x="E", y="fraction_connected", hue='V').
